# How to fix button resize on iPhone X using autoresizing

Tags: ios, swift

First apologies in advance for question as it does not require coding only if its the required solution.

I am walking my way through constraints and auto resize with swift 4. I am having one slight issue while auto resizing without using constraints as that messes up the buttons positioning and size. See below how my UI buttons stack up.

**iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 8, iPhone SE all look same and buttons aligned perfect**

[image]

**iPhone X - Image appears stretched**

[image]

**iphone 4S - Image appears compressed inward**

[image]

**All I did was for each button set autoresizing as seen below**

[image]

Is there a way I can make iPhone X maintain same image aspect ratios?

Thanks

Comment: using constraints, rather than autoresize-masks... maybe?

Comment: Do you want the buttons to maintain their sizes as well as aspect ratios, or only their aspect ratios?

Comment: @LGP for instance if button A size is 100 x 50 on iPhone 8, then on iPhone X size should maintain same ratio like 200x100 so it fits into phone screen size

Comment: @holex i have spent last 2 days watching youtube videos on constraints but most are either vertical or horizontal layouts of buttons but not a mix of both

Comment: Yes, I understand about the aspect ratio, but should they grow/shrink on larger/smaller screens?

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover, dealing with constraints is a really complicated job, comparing to autoresize-masks at least, but it is the only way to create consistent layouts for every screen-size on the most easiest way: you can set up ratios, vertical or horizontal spaces, dynamic widths and heights, hugging priorities, etc... it is worth to learn it and there is no cheap way.

Comment: @LGP yes they should grow / shrink without been distorted.

,holex I am constantly searching the web for more helpful info and tuts

Comment: iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 8, iPhone SE these iPhones have same height-width ratio, but iPhone 4S and iPhoneX have different height-width ratio. So you can handle it with autoresizing. You should go with constraints.

Comment: I think you need to use constraints. With constraints you have both aspect ratio constraints and proprtional constraints. Those will do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you should use constraints to achieve the desired result. Using `aspect-ratio` and `proportional` constraints you should be able to scale the buttons accordingly.

---

**EDIT**

There are many ways you can do this with autolayout. Below I enumerate each step I performed to achieved it.

1. Create a view, rename it to contentView. This view will hold the three buttons. Center it **horizontally** and set a **bottom** constraint: [image]

---

2. Create **height** and **width** constraints for the contentView in relation to its superview, and change them to be **proportional**: [image]

---

3. Create a view inside contentView, rename it redView and change its background color to red. Pin it to **top**, **left** and **right**. Finally, add a **proportional height** constraint (0.5) related to contentView: [image]
   [image]

---

4. Create a view inside contentView, rename it to blueView and change its background color to blue. Pin it to the **bottom** and **right**. Also, create a **top space constraint** between this view and the redView (value 16): [image]

**There will be some storyboard errors, don't worry, we will fix them shortly.**

---

5. Create a view inside contentView, rename it to greenView and change its background color to green. Similarly to the blueView, pin it to the **bottom** and **left**. Also, add a **trailing space constraint** between greenView and blueView (value 32): [image]

---

6. Finally, create **equal height** and **equal width** constraints between greenView and blueView.
   [image]

---

That's it, now you should add buttons and/or images to each view and perform additional logic to achieve your desired final result (adding round corners and such).

Comment: This is smart. Awesome job @Kévin.

Comment: Thank you. I was going to post each step that I performed to create the layout, but it was becoming too long. ;)

Comment: Funny enough I was about to ask for that because I am lost in some areas. One in particular is how you added constraints to the safe area since its greyed out on mine. If you can do a quick video, that would be awesome

Comment: Ok, I will make a video showing the step-by-step I made. But, unfortunately, I will only be able to upload it later today...

Comment: There you go, updated my answer with additional information.